# Rubber electrical tape safe under code for attics?

Tags: attic, wire, rubber

I'm buying a house.  The attic had a wire with frayed outer insulation. I negotiated repair of the cable.  The seller has responded that the repairperson wrapped the fray with rubber electrical tape (I presume 3M tempex or a similar product).  It has a continuous max temperature rating of 190 degrees farenheit. Attic temperatures here (Phoenix) reach the 180s during the summer.  I have questionable faith in this repair.  Is there anything in The National Electric Code that says this repair is improper?

Comment: Was this the outer jacket or the wire itself?

Comment: Electrical tape is usually vinyl. Are we talking about something else?

Comment: And what sort of cable? The only type that could really fray is old fabric cloth-covered cable.

Comment: Is this a repair of cable jacketing, or of wire insulation within the jacket?

Comment: Yeah, the electrical code has a whole section of rules for electrical wiring operating in spaces with temperatures beyond norms. I see on the web where you got "180s" that's 82-87 degrees C and it's also anecdotal, and could be more.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We're eager to help, but will need more information (e.g. a picture of the damaged cable, or the repair, or both).

Comment: Outer wire. Is fraying. Seems to be cloth. Yes this is rubber linerless tape not vinyl. Does anyone have access to the code section that deals with temperatures beyond norms. I need something to cite to my real estate agent.

Comment: Yeah, wow, I'm reading NEC 310.15(a)(3) and lookout.  I'm not even sure it's legal to use THHN wire since you're within 5C of *its* thermal limits.  What is the type of wire?

Comment: @Joshua Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: If linerless splicing tape was used that's usually 130c the type. It's good to 221f

Comment: Can I ask what all is housed in this attic? Is it just wiring in the joist-space and a vent or two sticking up through the roof, or is there a bunch of HVAC equipment and ductwork living there as well?

Comment: some ductwork I believe.

Comment: I'm mostly looking for a section of code to cite to the seller that states this was an inadequate repair.  I believe the proper repair is to splice with new wire and use a junction box on either end.